# How to check column names present in all the tables in Database

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016

I was trying to write a query in which I could check if certain column names are present in all the tables in a database. 
in an effort to avoid hardship I was trying to access all the  tables at once and check if columns are present in the tables.
I was able to find the code below to get the table name :

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_CATALOG='SAMPLE_DB_NAME'
```

I am unable to get inside each table and check the column names.

If any one could help me with the query to get into each table and check the columns names which are constant for all the tables.

Comment: So, if I understand your inferred question correctly, you're looking for tables which don't have the column `N'{Your Column Name}`?

Comment: Yes , but there are multiple columns(Total 6) that i want to search in a table and my database has total 36 tables.

Comment: @RAMAN BHATIA - you can try below query suggested by me. you can pass as many as columns you want to find using IN Clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT  TABLE_CATALOG,
        TABLE_NAME,
        COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_CATALOG='SAMPLE_DB_NAME' 
AND CHARINDEX('Status',COLUMN_NAME) = 1 -- Specify the column name to check the column is existed
                                        --- in the datbase of all available tables
```

Answer (score 0):

**The below query will list all the table names where any given specific fields does not exist.**

```
SELECT distinct TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE  TABLE_CATALOG='testdb' 
and TABLE_NAME not in(
select object_name(object_id) ObjectName from sys.COLUMNS where name  in ('YourfieldName1', 'YourfieldName2')
```

**The below query will list all the table names where it will find the fields specified.**

```
select object_name(object_id) ObjectName, * 
from sys.COLUMNS where name  in ('YourfieldName1', 'YourfieldName2')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--List of tables
SELECT * FROM sys.tables

--List of Columns
SELECT * FROM sys.columns

--List of Columns Tables joined
SELECT tbl.[name] AS TableName, clm.[name] AS ColumnName FROM sys.tables as tbl INNER JOIN sys.columns as clm ON tbl.[object_id] = clm.[object_id]



-You can check with the column name if the column exist in all tables 
USE MyDataBase
DECLARE @TableCount INT
DECLARE @FoundTables INT
SET @TableCount = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.tables)
SET @FoundTables = ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(tbl.[name])) AS NumberOfTables FROM sys.tables as tbl INNER JOIN sys.columns as clm ON tbl.[object_id] = clm.[object_id] WHERE clm.[name] = 'YourColumnName')

IF @FoundTables = @TableCount
 BEGIN
   PRINT 'The column is present in all tables'
 END
ELSE
 BEGIN 
   PRINT 'The column is not present in all tables'
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

With this query you can get all columns present in all tables

```
WITH DistinctColumnNames AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Column_Name 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T ON C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA AND C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME AND C.TABLE_CATALOG = T.TABLE_CATALOG
    WHERE T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND T.TABLE_CATALOG='SAMPLE_DB_NAME' AND T.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND T.TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'sys%'
)
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM DistinctColumnNames DC
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
    WHERE T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND T.TABLE_CATALOG='SAMPLE_DB_NAME' AND T.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND T.TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'sys%'
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
        WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME AND C.COLUMN_NAME = DC.COLUMN_NAME
         AND T.TABLE_CATALOG='SAMPLE_DB_NAME' AND T.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo')
)
```